# Substitute/replace odd or even or custom occurrence of text within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering

Excel cell has text as A-B-C-D-E-F. Replace 1, 3, 5th occurrence of '-' by '~' using an Excel formula. Output must be **A~B-C~D-E~F**

Without using nested SUBSTITUTE function as below

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", "~", 1), "-", "~", 3), "-", "~", 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN({"~","-"},,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"))
```

Comment: Sir you are `Brilliant` as always!!

Comment: Chapeau, monsieur!

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines of using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTJOIN()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN({"~","-","~","-","~"},,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

### Replace Alternating Delimiters

**Spill**

```
=LET(data,A2:A11,dlb,"-",dla,"~",
MAP(data,LAMBDA(r,LET(
    ts,TEXTSPLIT(r,,dlb),
    IFERROR(CONCAT(ts&VSTACK(INDEX(VSTACK(dla,dlb),
        MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ts)-1)-1,2)+1),"")),
        IF(r="","",r))))))
```

[image]

**Single Cell (Excel Table)**

```
=LET(data,A2,dlb,"-",dla,"~",
    ts,TEXTSPLIT(data,,dlb),
IFERROR(CONCAT(ts&VSTACK(INDEX(VSTACK(dla,dlb),
    MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ts)-1)-1,2)+1),"")),
    IF(data="","",data)))
```